# emberjs: animation when removing element

Tags: ember.js

My app is displaying a table of "grouped fields" with a delete button for each group of fields.

By example: 
firstname lastname age deleteButton
firstname lastname age deleteButton
firstname lastname age deleteButton
firstname lastname age deleteButton

Currently when clicking on a deleteButton, the linked row is automatically removed by the backend binding.

I would like to make an animation on the row to be removed...

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe you can try this?
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willDestroyElement